# Prevent an eval'ed statement from returning its RHS return value

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm returning the value of an eval call to a variable I am saving as the output. But I don't want the output of the `testFn()` to be the output of the eval call.

In non-eval calls, no output is generated, but `eval` does something that makes it also spit out the last expression or statement. I tried having them assigned to variables, but that doesn't work. It still returns the `0.5` value for the eval output as seen below.

```js
const val = eval(
`
function accumulator (sum) {
  return function (n) {
    return sum += n;
  };
}

const testFn = typeof accumulator(3) === 'function' && accumulator(3);

if (testFn) {
  let dumpReturn = testFn(-4);
  dumpReturn = testFn(1.5);
}
`
);

document.write(val);
```

Is this normal behavior, and if so, is there a way to not have this returned as the `eval` value without adding an arbitrary line following the last statement such as `'undefined';`?

Comment: Can you wrap it in `eval` so that it was possible to run it and see what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "silence the output"? Javascript code doesn't produce output by itself, only if it calls functions that produce output, modify the DOM, etc.

Comment: If you don't assign the return value to a variable or pass it as an argument to another function, it goes to the void just like you want.

Comment: Are you calling the function from the browser console? That's a read-eval-print loop, so it prints the return value. But that has nothing to do with what happens when you use the code in a program.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Let me try and update my question with a snippet so that it's readily observable. Give me a second.

Comment: No, I'm calling it from a webworker and the output if any is saved in the webworker as well.

Comment: @Barmar Okay, I've updated my question. It contains what I'm having a problem with.

Comment: @zerkms Updated the question with a snippet containing everything inside the eval call.

Comment: Simply add an line with `undefined;` at the end of your string. eval returns the *completion* of evaluated statement, whatever that means exactly, I'll guess it's like the whole code had an return before.. But now a simple question: why do you even declare val in that case ?

Comment: @Kaiido That's an approach I've tried. Sorry I should have specified that I actually don't want that as I'm evaluating user code and their output needs to be displayed if they choose to write out `accumulator(3)(5)` for instance. But if I add that line, they will always see the `undefined` since the `testFn` is part of the larger `tail` function.

Comment: @mythereal "and their output needs to be displayed" --- that's the current behaviour.

Comment: Then I clearly don't get what you are doing... If you want to store a variable (like testFn), either add an no-op call to this variable so it becomes the returned value, either store it from the evaled code itself. But here I don't know what you want to do...

Comment: Ugh. I figured out the right solution. I kept the `tail` function (which includes the testFn) appended during the evaluation of userCode, but it's not necessary. The `tail` function was only to be used when performing assertion tests on the user code. Not for the output. Thanks for all the help everyone.